# Can I force an Angular #variableName for an HTML element to return an ElementRef?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material

If I create a button like this:

```
<button #myButton>My Button</button>
```

...and use `ViewChild` like this:

```
@ViewChild('myButton', { static: true }) createButton: ElementRef;
```

...then `createButton` is (as declared) an `ElementRef`, where `createButton.nativeElement` is a DOM element.

If, however, I do this:

```
<button mat-raised-button #myButton>My Button</button>
```

...my variable is no longer an `ElementRef`, but a `MatButton` instance instead.

I'd really like the variable to remain an `ElementRef`. How would I do that?

I've seen notation like `<form #myForm="ngForm"...` the makes sure a variable is an `NgForm` in particular, or `<input #firstName="ngModel"...>` to get an `NgModel`.

I tried `<button #myButton="elementRef" mat-raised-button...`, and a few different variations on that theme, but they all produced compilation errors. Is there something like that that would do the trick?

This is a very poorly documented aspect of Angular. I can't even find the proper terminology for these kinds of references/variables. Hash reference? Hash variable? Herbert? And the only reason I know about things like `#firstName="ngModel"` is from seeing examples, not from documentation that spells out the general concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify what token you want to query, you can use the [**`ViewChild#read`**](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) parameter, as stated in Angular docs:

> read - Used to read a different token from the queried elements.

**Example**:

```js
@ViewChild('myButton', { read: ElementRef, static: true }) createButton: ElementRef;
```

[**Check the demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcs78b)

---

> *This is a very poorly documented aspect of Angular. I can't even find the proper terminology for these kinds of references/variables. Hash
> reference? Hash variable? Herbert? And the only reason I know about
> things like #firstName="ngModel" is from seeing examples, not from
> documentation that spells out the general concept.*

About this, there's a dedicated section for this that you can check [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables).

Comment: Thanks! I guess if I'd known to call it a "template variable" I'd have found documentation sooner. It's a shame, however, there doesn't seem to be a way within the HTML to do what `read` does, in case you wanted to make a reference to the variable as an ElementRef inside the HTML itself.

Comment: True, @kshetline. In this case, Ingo Bürk's answer shows a clean way to do this :)

Answer (score 2):

Given the question, @developer033's answer is correct. However, the same question can be asked when wanting to use the template reference variable directly in the template and not through `@ViewChild`. For completeness I'll include an answer for that here.

The short answer: no, you can't. But we *can* make it work by just writing our own directive as a proxy:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[injectRef]",
  exportAs: "elementRef",
})
export class InjectRefDirective extends ElementRef<unknown> {
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef<unknown>) {
    super(elementRef.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

And then use as

```
<button injectRef #myRef="elementRef"></button>
```

Comment: Cool trick. Maybe you should do a PR for the Angular code base to add this.